# Why do portions of SSH public (and private) keys overlap?

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-keygen

Specifically, why are the first 25 characters of ssh Ed25519 public keys always the same?

For example, if I make 5 keys with `ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519`, the first 25 characters are always `AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAI`.

I assume this is a preamble or header of some sort, but I would love to know the actual answer.

Comment: Crossdupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5944/why-do-all-ssh-rsa-keys-begin-with-aaaab3nzac1yc . _New format_ OpenSSH _private key_ files similarly are the base64 encoding of data that begins with several mostly-constant XDR-formatted strings, although the key type/algorithm is some way in; new format is automatically used for ed25519 (because no old format exists for that type) and you only need to specify -o for other types.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The string is base64 encoded. When decoded, it produces the string `\0\0\0\vssh-ed25519\0`. This identifies the type of the key. In this case an [EdDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) key.

Comment: The `\0\0\0\v` part is 11 written as a 32 bit number and is indicating the length of the string `ssh-ed25519`.